# Firebase Simulator: Cannot test writing data that is not JSON

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

Since the simulator only allow writing JSON data, I cannot test scenario like this:

```
Location: users/uid123/age  
Data: 25
```

I can only test:

```
Location: users/uid123  
Data: {"age":25}
```

But they are different if I only allow write access to `/users/$uid/age` but not `/users/$uid`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The Firebase Database stores JSON, so you can test in the emulator exactly what the database can store. Can you show the code-snippet that would accomplish the write you're trying to simulate?

Comment: Hi, here is an example from the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set): `adaNameRef.child('first').set('Ada');`.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

[image: Writing a value of 25 in the simulator]

The rules are irrelevant to the operation in this case, I just used the database that I happened to have open at the moment.

Comment: Thx! I was trying data with the wrong format and it says invalid JSON so I thought only JSON was allowed.